# Unable to cast generic type to interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, casting

I have those types:

```
public interface ICommand {}

public class RemoveCommand<T>: ICommand
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand: ICommand
{
    void HandleCommand(TCommand command);
}

public class RemoveCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<RemoveCommand<T>>
{
   public void HandleCommand(SoftRemoveCommand<T> command)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

While I was trying to resolve my ICommandHandler using Castle Windsor I received a cast exceptions. So I wrote this:

```
var obj = new RemoveCommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>();
bool t1 = obj is ICommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>; //return false!
bool t2 = obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(ICommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>); //also false!
```

So my question is: 
Why my RemoveCommandHandler is not assignable from ICommandHandler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your generic class declaration is`RemoveCommandHandler<T>`. So If you have class `RemoveCommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>`, this means that your `T` is `RemoveCommand<MyClass>`.

So you should change `RemoveCommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>` to `RemoveCommandHandler<MyClass>` and the code should work:

```
var obj = new RemoveCommandHandler<MyClass>();
bool t1 = obj is ICommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>;  // returns true
```

Although for second check you need to switch sides:

```
bool t2 = typeof(ICommandHandler<RemoveCommand<MyClass>>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());  // returns true
```

Comment: Thnak you! I should have mentioned it by myself.